# Flink: Using the timestamp which are included inside the message for EventTime windowing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am taking the message from the Kafka streamer into Flink. The message have `Record_time` field included into it and I want to apply the time window based on the `Record_time`.

Can I extract or use the `Record_time` field to assign Timestamp to that message? As all the methods of interface `TimestampExtractor` are deprecated, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`TimestampExtractor` has been deprecated and replaced by `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` and `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks`.

`AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` extracts timestamps for each record and is periodically queried for the current watermark.

´AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks` extracts timestamps for each record as well. In addition it is called for each record to extract a watermark. This is helpful if watermarks are encoded in special records.

Comment: Currently I am using `FlinkKafkaConsumer09`, this timestamp extraction feature of `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks` is also available with if or is it only available with `FlinkKafkaConsumer010`. I am using kafka 0.9 jar.

Comment: all Flink Kafka consumers support both types of assigners. Maybe you have an old version of the connector? You should make sure that all Flink dependencies have the same version.